# Get Xml Data From URL

Tags: c#

How can I get a list of items straight from the xml file that is on the host?
More precisely, I want to This xml file http://gamerpro.webd.pl/data/modlist.xml I pulled out a list of items and listened to the code

```
If (! File.Exists ("received list of items"))
{
Await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync (new Uri (url + "received item list"), dir + "received item list");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ReadXMLfromURL
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Class1.
    /// </summary>
    class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String URLString = "http://localhost/books.xml";
            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader (URLString);

            while (reader.Read()) 
            {
                switch (reader.NodeType) 
                {
                    case XmlNodeType.Element: // The node is an element.
                        Console.Write("<" + reader.Name);

                        while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute()) // Read the attributes.
                            Console.Write(" " + reader.Name + "='" + reader.Value + "'");
                        Console.Write(">");
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType.Text: //Display the text in each element.
                        Console.WriteLine (reader.Value);
                        break;
                    case XmlNodeType. EndElement: //Display the end of the element.
                        Console.Write("</" + reader.Name);
                        Console.WriteLine(">");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
// Make your request
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestURL);
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/xml");
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

// Parse your response
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    using (Stream httpResponseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result)
    {
        XDocument responseXML = XDocument.Load(httpResponseStream);

        // My Chosen element is the element you're looking for
        IEnumerable<XElement> myElements = responseXML.Root.Elements("MyChosenElement");

        foreach (XElement myEl in myElements)
        {
            // Access each element like this myEl.Child
            // Do what you'd like with it
        }
    }
}
```